# How to create a function to extract values from repeated start/end string markers?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string

This is a nested JSON string. It's an output from an API call stored in a dataframe.

Example JSON string:

```
[{'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_shortname': 'US', 'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_fullname': 'US', 
'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_name_id': '58346rjf-4jfuf-3fjtr-dd433-53jfsk', 
'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_shortname': 'UK',
'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_fullname': 'UK',
'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_name_id': '34634jfe-5rufm-2fmjd-gj453-68fdkdf'}]
```

Start String:

```
'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_fullname': '
```

End String:

```
', 'somethingrelated_fjf74jg-fjfj3-475f-644h-5348fjdkg_something_name_id'
```

Expected Output: `[US,UK]`

I'm trying to get to place where I can extract just "US" or "UK" or any other abbreviation that falls inside that space without using string position as that might be inconsistent.

Comment: That's not a JSON string. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: It looks like Python representation. Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it, then process the list of dictionaries to get what you want.

Comment: Don't do this with string processing.

Comment: If it's a json object then just use the json library? If that string is inside a file (or is quoted with strings) then just `json.load` on the file, or `json.loads` on the string.

Comment: Is there always only **one** item on the list? If so, `d = eval(VARIABLE)` then `output = [i for i in d[0].values() if len(i) == 2]`